Pandas groupby - group columns to a list of count of row values
I want to group my dataframe according to a column [Say: Release] with a sum of values from other rows in a customized representation.
My Dataframe:
|  Release  | Pass | Fail | Total |
|:---------:|:----:|:----:|:-----:|
| release_a | 10   | 20   | 30    |
| release_a | 5    | 45   | 50    |
| release_a | 5    | 23   | 28    |
| release_a | 20   | 67   | 87    |
| release_a | 87   | 11   | 98    |
| release_b | 2    | 5    | 7     |
| release_b | 10   | 45   | 55    |
| release_b | 64   | 33   | 97    |
| release_c | 3    | 15   | 18    |
| release_c | 104  | 89   | 193   |
| release_c | 98   | 87   | 185   |

Output expected:
|  Release  |         Summary        |
|:---------:|:----------------------:|
| release_a | [Pass: 40, Fail: 55]   |
| release_b | [Pass: 76, Fail: 83]   |
| release_c | [Pass: 205, Fail: 191] |

I tried using groupby and agg, but couldnt achieve my expected result.
I  used the below codes:
df.groupby(['Release Name'],as_index=False).agg({'Pass': lambda x: x.to_numpy().tolist()})

df['Release Name'].map(df.value_counts('Pass'))


Please provide a [mre] of the input data, images are not acceptable. Also your input and output are currently identical.

You could use groupby.sum, then agg:
out = (df
   .drop(columns=['Total'], errors='ignore')
   .groupby('Release').sum()
   .agg(lambda x: list(zip(x.index, x.values)), axis=1)
   .reset_index(name='Summary')
)

Output:
     Release                     Summary
0  release_a  [(Pass, 127), (Fail, 166)]
1  release_b    [(Pass, 76), (Fail, 83)]
2  release_c  [(Pass, 205), (Fail, 191)]

As dictionary (.agg(lambda x: dict(zip(x.index, x.values)), axis=1)):
     Release                     Summary
0  release_a  {'Pass': 127, 'Fail': 166}
1  release_b    {'Pass': 76, 'Fail': 83}
2  release_c  {'Pass': 205, 'Fail': 191}

Alternatively, using a single groupby.apply:
cols = ['Pass', 'Fail']

out = (df
   .groupby('Release')
   .apply(lambda x: x[cols].sum().to_dict(),
          include_groups=False)
   .reset_index(name='Summary')
)


both answers helped me. thank you very much!

You can also Use numpy for Huge datasets.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = {
    'Release': ['release_a', 'release_a', 'release_a', 'release_a', 'release_a', 
                'release_b', 'release_b', 'release_b', 
                'release_c', 'release_c', 'release_c'],
    'Pass': [10, 5, 5, 20, 87, 2, 10, 64, 3, 104, 98],
    'Fail': [20, 45, 23, 67, 11, 5, 45, 33, 15, 89, 87],
    'Total': [30, 50, 28, 87, 98, 7, 55, 97, 18, 193, 185]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

'''# Convert the DataFrame columns to NumPy arrays
release = df['Release'].values
pass_values = df['Pass'].values
fail_values = df['Fail'].values
'''

col_arrays = {col: df[col].values for col in df.columns}

release = col_arrays['Release']
pass_values = col_arrays['Pass']
fail_values = col_arrays['Fail']

# Find unique releases and initialize arrays to store sums
unique_releases,indices = np.unique(release, return_inverse =True)
print(unique_releases)#['release_a' 'release_b' 'release_c']

pass_sums = np.zeros(unique_releases.shape)
fail_sums = np.zeros(unique_releases.shape)

# Aggregate sums using NumPy
np.add.at(pass_sums, indices, pass_values)
np.add.at(fail_sums, indices, fail_values)
print(pass_sums)#[127.  76. 205.]
print(fail_sums)#[166.  83. 191.]

summary = [f"[Pass: {p}, Fail: {f}]" for p, f in zip(pass_sums, fail_sums)] 
print(summary)#['[Pass: 127.0, Fail: 166.0]', '[Pass: 76.0, Fail: 83.0]', '[Pass: 205.0, Fail: 191.0]']


result_df = pd.DataFrame({'Release': unique_releases, 'Summary': summary})
print(result_df)
'''
    Release                     Summary
0  release_a  [Pass: 127.0, Fail: 166.0]
1  release_b    [Pass: 76.0, Fail: 83.0]
2  release_c  [Pass: 205.0, Fail: 191.0]
'''

